# android make an object from extends AsyncTask and send it to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, ssh, android-asynctask

I have problem with create an object from sshconnection that extends AsyncTask class..

My class is as below

```
public class sshconnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String results;

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(User, IP, Port);
            session.setPassword(Pass);

            // Avoid asking for key confirmation
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(prop);

            session.connect();


            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channel.setOutputStream(baos);
            channel.setCommand(CMD);
            channel.connect();



            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if(channel.isClosed()){
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();


            return baos.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      //  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtipinfo);
      //  txt.setText("Executed");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, baos.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }


}
```

and this is when i called it in button click

```
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_conn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         CMD = "ls";

         new sshconnection().execute(User,Pass,IP,CMD);

        }
    });
```

Until here my code is work fine and I can make ssh connection to my server.

**My problem** is that I want to create an object from sshconnection class to send it to another activity to reuse the connection of the ssh to sends other ssh commands to my server.

If there is another way to do that even if i have to change AsyncTask class .. Or use anthing else like new threads.
Please tell me how to do that and where i make changes in my code.

Thanks a lot for everyone.

Comment: An asynctask instance can only be used/executed once.

Comment: Asynctask is a thread, not an object. You can't send it.

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCătălin this is Java we're talking about - everything other than primitives are Objects. A Thread is an Object. It's definitely possible to pass the AsyncTask object, though it's not possible to update the background thread it executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**

```
public class sshconnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public String returncmd=null;



        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {

                //Sndlist=args[0];
                //result=-11;
                //String results;

                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                Session session = jsch.getSession("admin", "10.0.0.1",22);

                session.setPassword("a");

                //Toast.makeText(null," user = " + ss, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Avoid asking for key confirmation
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setConfig(prop);

                session.connect();


            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            channel.setOutputStream(baos);
            channel.setCommand("/ip hotspot user add name=nnnnnn profile=120");
            channel.connect();



            byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
            while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if(i<0)break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if(channel.isClosed()){
                    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
            }

            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();

            returncmd = baos.toString();
            return returncmd;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //  TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtipinfo);
            //  txt.setText("Executed");
            //mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            //Toast.makeText(UserDetail.this, baos.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }



    } // end of class sshconnection
```

and you can call as follow:

new sshconnection().execute;

Answer (score 2):

An AsyncTask is not designed for your use-case. Regardless of whether or not you could get it to work, you shouldn't.

From the [AsyncTask documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#Class_Overview):

> "AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few
>   seconds at the most.)"

An AsyncTask is designed to run once for one operation and then return info to the UI. You should probably designate your SSH connection to run in a service and use Thread and ThreadPool methods to handle this.

Comment: Yup, you can definitely use a thread. Here's a good guide: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: That gives you the basics of creating a thread. You can keep a reference to the Thread that's created in order to pass it where you want it to go.

Comment: I won't go into too much detail, but basically, you can create a thread, and then in your run() method have a wait-loop, that basically checks for any new inputs every 100-500 milliseconds. Then, wherever you have your Thread object reference, you can update the inputs with whatever new information you have.

Comment: Thank you Mr.  Shadesblade  .. I found the solution that you give it to me before .. I read about it and i found the solution .. I will post the solution now.